# How to convert tables into Spring Data entities?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I’m looking for some help in converting the following tables into Spring Data Entities. I was somewhat able to do it but I can’t figure out enforcing the on delete and on update constraints. I have a users table that will contain info about a user. The conversations table will then have a conversation id and 2 columns to represent both id’s of the participating users. I’m writing my Solution in Kotlin, but I’m fine with advice in Java as well. Using Postgres. At the end of the day, I just want to end up with these 2 tables with the ability to change the primary key in the users table and have that carry over to the conversations table.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    bio character varying(255),
    first_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    username character varying(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    zip_code character varying(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE conversations (
    convoid BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id1 uuid REFERENCES users(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    user_id2 uuid REFERENCES users(id) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

Here's what I tried:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(

        @Id //primary key
        var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var firstName: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var lastName: String,

        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        var username: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var password: String,

        @Transient 
        var confirmPassword: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var zipCode: String,

        @Column(nullable=true)
        var bio: String?

)

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "conversations")
data class Conversation(

        @Id //primary key
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val convoID: Long,

        @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id1")
        val user1: User, //FK of user table PK

        @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id2")
        val user2: User, //FK of user table PK

        @Transient
        var participants: List<WebSocketSession>

)
```

I'm trying to update the primary key in the users table but it isn't allowing me due to foreign key constraint. Clearly the Cascade isn't working.

Comment: Intellij has a tool. Go to persistence tab and u can create your entity class from tables. But u have to add your foreign keys on your own

Comment: Hrrmm I know some JPA providers (Hibernate for example) do not allow you to change the primary key

Answer (score 0):

In JPA relations only work in 1 way, in other to have `Converation` deleted when `User` is deleted you need to have `@OneToMany` relation to `Converation` from `User`. Same thing applies for update as well.

So adding property like this inside `User` should solve your problem:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
val conversations: List<Conversation>
```

**UPDATE**

JPA creates separate table, it is usually solved by adding `mappedBy = "mappingFieldName"` to  `@OneToMany`, but considering your case where you have 2 fields this is a bit tricky and much broader problem. You will either have to do a lot of custom querying or simply keep duplicate entries, meaning that for each new Conversation you will actually have 2 of them, so then you can say `mappedBy = "user1"`, just remember to every time save 2 Conversations, 1 where user1 is actual user1 and another where you swap user1 and user2.

Comment: I just added this, and it ended up creating a 3rd table in the db called user_conversations. Hmm